# Why isn't sidekiq daemonizing?

Tags: sidekiq

Sick to the back teeth of sidekiq:

```
#   sidekiq -C config.yml
---
:verbose: false
:daemonize: true
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency: 25
# Set timeout to 8 on Heroku, longer if you manage your own systems.
:timeout: 30
:queues:
  - [often, 7]
  - [default, 5]
  - [seldom, 3]
```

I run

```
sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
         s
        ss
   sss  sss         ss
   s  sss s   ssss sss   ____  _     _      _    _
   s     sssss ssss     / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
  s         sss         \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
  s sssss  s             ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
  ss    s  s            |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
  s     s s                                           |_|
        s s
       sss
       sss
```

and it doesn't daemonize. It just hangs there. However, it does log to the logfile specified and create a pid.

Here's my log:

```
2014-05-08T11:13:58Z 12036 TID-9g3gg INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
2014-05-08T11:13:58Z 12036 TID-9g3gg INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2014-05-08T11:13:58Z 12036 TID-9g3gg INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2014-05-08T11:13:58Z 12036 TID-y7cwk INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.0.1 with redis options {}
```

I think it is daemonized. However, it doesn't return me back to the command line?

Answer (score 1):

The option is `daemon`, not daemonize.